# pygame zoom in and out implementation

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, zooming

I am trying to make a tile based rpg that has many functionalities to it. As it stands i am trying to make a zoom out and zoom in function. Can anyone help me implement a zoom in function?

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import TileSheet

# Screen
width, height = 800, 800
# Load Window
pygame.init()
# 800x800 pixels
DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H = width, height
canvas = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test Tileset')
running = True
# Camera
camx, camy = 0, 0
zoom = 1
# Sheets
cellsTwo = TileSheet.tilesetTwo()
# Test
hover_mouse = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 0, 0)

# Tiles
tile_two = cellsTwo[1]
tiletwo = tile_two.get_rect()
tiletwo.center = (16, 16)
# Player
player = cellsTwo[3]
player_center = player.get_rect()

player_center.center = (0, 0)

move_up, move_down, move_left, move_right = False, False, False, False
# Display screen
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        # User input
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Pressing escape will close the window
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            # Moving Player
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move_down = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                shoot = mixer.Sound("Sound/laser.wav")
                shoot.play()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # Stop Moving Player
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move_down = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL:
            if event.y == -1:
                if zoom != 3:
                    zoom += 1
                if zoom == 0:
                    print("Original: "+str(zoom))
                if zoom < 0:
                    print("Zoom In: "+str(zoom))
                if zoom > 0:
                    print("Zoom Out: "+str(zoom))
            else:
                if zoom != -3:
                    zoom -= 1
                if zoom == 0:
                    print("Original: "+str(zoom))
                if zoom < 0:
                    print("Zoom In: "+str(zoom))
                if zoom > 0:
                    print("Zoom Out: "+str(zoom))
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            pygame.display.set_caption("mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
            x, y = event.pos
            hover_mouse.center = event.pos
    # Movement
    if move_up:
        player_center.centery -= 1
    if move_down:
        player_center.centery += 1
    if move_left:
        player_center.centerx -= 1
    if move_right:
        player_center.centerx += 1

    # Window Update and Display Update
    canvas.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(canvas, (0, 0))
    # Green Grass Loop
    screen.blit(tile_two, (tiletwo.x - camx, tiletwo.y - camy))
    # Player
    camx = player_center.x
    camy = player_center.y
    screen.blit(player, (player_center.x-camx+(DISPLAY_W/2), player_center.y-camy+(DISPLAY_H/2)))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have set up a camera that moves the player, and its always "centered" around the player. There is one way I tried to zoom in and that was using transform. Unfortunately, transforming all images on the screen each frame is resource intensive and results in a crash. I already have a scroll wheel attached to some zoom numbers. What I want to achieve is x0.25 and x2 smooth zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Do not zoom each tile separately, but zoom a section of the map:

- Define the rectangular area ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) to be displayed on the screen
- Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the size of this area.
- Draw the scene on the *Surface*
- Scale the *Surface* to the screen size.
- [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the scaled *surface* on the screen.